# Bitmap data hittest

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, hittest

I was helped by some people for this code and I'm a little lost. This code creates two zigzag lines that fall in a loop. I want to use bitmap data hittest with these lines, just to hit a simple object at the bottom of the screen, but I do not know how. I found the example of Mike Chambers but I do not know what to change to make it work for me. How can I apply it to my code?

bitmap data hittest example : http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/

```
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
var objectSpawner: Timer;
var fallers: Array;


function initGame(): void {
    fallers = [];
    objectSpawner = new Timer(1000);
    objectSpawner.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, createEnemy);
    objectSpawner.start();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropEnemies);
}
function createEnemy(e: TimerEvent): void {
    var enemy: Faller = new Faller();
    enemy.y = -stage.stageHeight;
    enemy.x = Math.random() * 380;
    MovieClip(enemy).cacheAsBitmap = true;
    addChild(enemy);
    fallers.push(enemy);
    drawConnectors();
}
function dropEnemies(e: Event): void {
    trace(fallers.length);
    for each(var mc: Faller in fallers) {
        mc.y += 10;
        if (mc.y > stage.stageHeight * 2) fallers.splice(fallers.indexOf(removeChild(mc)), 1);
    }
    drawConnectors();
}
function drawConnectors(): void {
    if (fallers.length == 0) return;
    var g: Graphics = this.graphics;
    g.clear();
    g.lineStyle(10,0xFFFFFF);
    var mc: Faller = fallers[0];
    g.moveTo(mc.x, mc.y);
    for each(mc in fallers) g.lineTo(mc.x, mc.y);
}
init()


function init():void
{
          var fallingThingsLeft:FallingThings = new FallingThings(stage.stageWidth / 2, stage.stageHeight);
          var fallingThingsRight:FallingThings = new FallingThings(stage.stageWidth / 2, stage.stageHeight);
          addChild(fallingThingsLeft);
          addChild(fallingThingsRight);
          fallingThingsRight.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
}
```

Comment: Well you haven't even tried doing such a check. The code is pretty straightforward - the check function is at line 16. It check two bitmap datas and uses points to align them with each other. This might help: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest()

Comment: Its been several days that I try all the possibilities and nothing happens. Could you, PLEASE, write me the code or show me how :)